# Running cronjob in NodeJS express triggers 3 times hosted on Google Kubernetes Engine with 3 nodes. How to run a cronjob within a node?

Tags: node.js, express, scheduled-tasks, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a scenario where I am sending email in every 1 days with using `node-cron` library in nodejs. The server is hosted in GKE with three nodes. But I am getting 3 emails each day, I believe from 3 different nodes running the same scheduled function. How can I overcome this so I get email from only one node?

I tried using `cluster` package

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
   initScheduleFunctions()
}
```

in my index.js.

Comment: feel free to share the more details, it's hard to answer with this much information, Generally, even if you are running the GKE cronjob it's possible to send a single email with Node even running 1000 of nodes. Cron job gets triggered once but not sure how things run on GKE, or what's YAML config, closing this out feel free to post a new question with more details.

Comment: We'd need to see your deployment spec, but likely your deployment has 3 replicas.  If you deployed your app via the GKE UI, it defaults to 3 replicas.

Since you are using GKE, you'll likely want to use a CronJob rather than a deployment.
You may also want to have a look at Cloud Run Jobs as well.

Comment: @GariSingh apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/vektor-dev-351106/vektor-pm-be:latest
        name: vektor-be
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4001
    targetPort: 4000
  selector:
    app: app
  type: ClusterIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your current deployment has 3 replicas:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: null
name: backend-deploy
spec: null
replicas: 3
selector: null
matchLabels: null
app: app
template:
  metadata: null
  labels:
    app: app
  spec:
    containers:
      - image: 'gcr.io/vektor-dev-351106/vektor-pm-be:latest'
        name: vektor-be
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
```

If you want to continue running your job as a Deployment, just modify replicas to 1:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: null
name: backend-deploy
spec: null
replicas: 1
selector: null
matchLabels: null
app: app
template:
  metadata: null
  labels:
    app: app
  spec:
    containers:
      - image: 'gcr.io/vektor-dev-351106/vektor-pm-be:latest'
        name: vektor-be
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But is there any other way we can keep 3 replicas as solve this issue?

Comment: What's the goal of having 3 replicas?

Comment: And where does the job get the info to send the messages?  Are you using some type of queue?

Comment: Doesn't 3 replicas meant for load balancing? 

I am using the following code to schedule the task and the function sends email. This cron is being run on all three replicas as I have initiated this jobs in express index.ts file.

`cron.schedule('0 8 */1 * *', sendFollowupEmail, {
      scheduled: true,
      timezone: "America/New_York"
    });`